# The Lost Expedition Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anyone know if there any secret passages inside Nchuand-Zel?

Comment: What do you mean by secret passages?

Answer (score 2):

I firmly believe there aren't, it is a "railroad" quest until you get to the ruins.

The wiki also doesn't mention anything of the kind.

The only note is that if you talk to Calcelmo you can enter after killing the spider, if you don't there's an adept lock keeping the door shut.